# Hibernate: enforcing same value for a column based on the value of another column

Tags: hibernate

Let's say I have a table

### sr_no  | name  | ref_id

1   | test  |  123
   2   | test  |  123
   3   | test1 |  456
   4   | test1 |  456
   5   | test2 |  NULL
   6   | test3 |  NULL

My problem is, I want to keep the values of "name" column consistent for the rows having same value of "ref_id" column. For ex, in above data if someone tries to update the name of row having sr_no=1 to say test123 then same name should start reflecting in the row with sr_no=2 as well because both have same value for the column ref_id which is 123.
Please note that I don't want to normalize the table by taking out name and ref_id in separate table because ref_id can also be NULL. So, I want to enforce it somehow using hibernate keeping the single table. Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

This issue isn't a job for Hibernate, it's a job for your functional code.

If you want the results as you've described about, use hibernate to retrieve a collection of Entities passing in REF_ID in your where clause.  Then make the same update to all of the Entities in your functional code.

Based on the data you've provided, I assume that you want to ignore this rule if the REF_ID is NOT NULL.  Again, you'd want to include this as a check in your functional code (not hibernate).

Finally - "because ref_id can also be NULL" isn't a valid reason not to denormalize.  You data-model would work perfectly well with NAME and REF_ID (nullable) being held in one table and your SR_NO having a foreign key to it.

E.g.

```
TEST_TABLE

ID | NAME | REF_ID
1 | test | 123
2 | test1 | 456
3 | test 2 | null
4 | test 3 | null

SR_TABLE

SR_NO | TEST_ID
1 | 1
2 | 1
3 | 2
4 | 2
5 | 3
6 | 6
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You are right that it's the job of functional code. But, I am working on a very mature project that has thousands of places where name is being updated. So, my goal is to do it at a centralized places so that it can handle all the cases. That's why I thought of doing it via hibernate. I am planning to use Hibernate interceptor for this purpose where I can intercept the save operation of the data and correspondingly update other rows. Is using interceptor a good idea for this purpose ?

Comment: I still think a non-hibernate solution would be better if possible.  I guess it depends exactly what code is being used in these thousands of places.  Are they methods you can change.  E.g. `public void save(Sr mySr) {...}` ?